# React Native onLayout nativeEvent.layout.y always returns 0

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating a grid of Views. I'm doing it using pure flex. i.e. no absolute positioning. Actual screenshot:

[image: Actual screenshot]

I need to know the positions of each View in the grid and for that I'm using the onLayout prop.
The problem is that the y value on evt.nativeEvent.layout is always zero, the rest of the values (x, height, width) are fine.
I'm testing only in Android, using Genymotion and a physical Sony Xperia device (both with Android 6.0.1).

Any ideas of why the y value is 0?

React Native version: 
 react-native: 0.40.0, react-native-cli: 1.2.0

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you put all views inside the top level view, or inside separate rows?

Comment: Separate rows..

Comment: If you use separate rows, then each cell's y coordinate is relative to its own row, so always 0.

Comment: Ok.. I was suspecting that so I ended up saving the row's Y position and then assigning it to the "cells".
Thanks for your help @HaitaoLi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I was suspecting that so I ended up saving the row's Y position and then assigning it to the "cells". Thanks for your help @HaitaoLi

Answer (score 0):

My version

```
const handleTabLayout = useCallback(
  (e: LayoutChangeEvent, index: number) => {
    const { width, x: nativeX } = e.nativeEvent.layout
    const x =
      Platform.OS === 'android' ? tabsWidth.reduce((sum, el, i) => (i < index ? sum + el.width : sum), 0) : nativeX
    if (tabsWidth[index]?.width !== width) {
      const newTabsWidth = tabsWidth.map((tw, twIndex) => (twIndex === index ? { ...tw, width, x } : tw))
      setTabsWidth(newTabsWidth)
    }
  },
  [tabsWidth]
)
```