# get absolute position in viewport of a view in react-native in android

Tags: react-native, measure

I have a problem to get the absolute position of my PicComponent.

I tried many things but nothing works really safe.

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "picapptwo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/react-native": "^3.4.0",
    "jest-expo": "26.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.17",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.13.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "rndebugger-open --expo",
    "storybook": "storybook start -p 7007"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@redux-offline/redux-offline": "^2.3.2",
    "buffer": "^5.1.0",
    "expo": "^26.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-remote-svg": "^1.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.9",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-observable": "^0.18.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^5.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

And my Pic Component:

```
 <View
         ref={el => this.container = el}
         // style={styles.container}
         onLayout={this.onLayout}
         // onLayout={(event) => {
         //this.find_dimesions(event.nativeEvent.layout)}}
    >
       <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={this.onPress}
       >
           <Image
              source={{uri: `data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${pic}`}}
                  style={styles.pic}
           />
       </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

I tried this:

```
onLayout = () => {
        this.container && this.container.measureInWindow(this.onMeasure);
    };

    onMeasure = (x, y, width, height) => {
        console.log('screens');
        console.log('screenx: ' + x + ' screenY: ' + y);
        this.props.onRenderPic(this.props.pic_index, x, y, width, height);
    };
```

But then the y value is not the same the gestureState from PanResponder is given when I touch. Its nearly 20 pixels smaller then the touch is given.

If y from measureInWindow is 123 the valuefrom gesturestate at the same point in the window is 148.

Here is the PanResponder function:

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder = (gestureState) => {
    const { dx, dy, moveX, moveY, numberActiveTouches } = gestureState;
}
```

moveY should be the same as the y value from the measureInWindow when I touch the screen on the top of the view.

So I tried the measure (and not the measureInWindow) function and took the callbacks first and second argument for the frame positions. But then I get allways 0 for x and y. Is this a bug in android?

So I tried:

```
<View
   ref={el => this.container = el}
   onLayout={(event) => { this.find_dimesions(event.nativeEvent.layout) }}
>
```

and the function:

```
find_dimesions(layout){
        const {x, y, width, height} = layout;
        this.props.onRenderPic(this.props.pic_index, x, y, width, height);
}
```

But this can`t work, because y is always 0 because its relative to its parent element.
Same problem here:
[React Native onLayout nativeEvent.layout.y always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861616/react-native-onlayout-nativeevent-layout-y-always-returns-0)

So I found this solution with the measureLayout function:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4753

Assume your render() method has the following content:

```
<ScrollView ref='scrollView'>
  ... whatever ...
  <Card ref='card'/>
</ScrollView>
```

This scrolls to the correct position:

```
this.refs.card.measureLayout(
  React.findNodeHandle(this.refs.scrollView),
  (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
    this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo(y);
  }
)
```

This does not scroll to the correct position:

```
this.refs.card.measure(
  (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
    this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo(y);
  }
)
```

But I don`t think it`s a good solution for me, because I don`t have a reference of the root component of my app.

Or what do you think can I do now, to get the absolute position of my views? I want to get the position on first rendering and every time it is rendered again. Maybe when a view is deleted and the animation stops.

And I have another problem with the positions.
The compnents are rendered in a Scrollview of the parent component:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
        {pics.map((pic, i) =>
          <StoryPic
            key={i}
            pic={pic}
            onRenderPic={onRenderPic}
            pic_index={i}
            story_index={story_index}
            removePic={removePic}
            // onPress={onPress}
          />
        )}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
```

They are positioned with flexDirection: 'row'.

If I have for example 5 PicComponents, they are all in the same row and on the same height.

This means the y value has to be the same for all of them. But sometimes I get for example 160 for the first one, and 140 for the last four ones.

Do you know what goes wrong here?

I would be very happy if you could help me here.